# Does this function auto-dereference a vector?

Tags: function, vector, rust

I am wondering why `list[0]` and `number_list[0]` have the same address.

To my understanding, we passed in a reference to `number_list` in `for_question4`, so list supposed to be a reference of `number_list`. When we called `list[0]` in `for_question4`, it is supposed to be the same as `&number_list[0]`.

But when I print the address, `list[0]` and `number_list[0]` are on the same address.
`&list[0]` and `&number_list[0]` are on the same address.

Does function auto-dereference the vector passed in to it? Is auto-dereference a thing in Rust? If so, in what condition would it do that?

```
fn for_question4(list: &[&str]) {
    println!("call index without reference {:p}", list[0]); // 0x103d23d5d

    println!("call index with reference {:p}", &list[0]); // 0x7fea9c405de0
}

fn main() {
    let number_list = vec!["1", "2", "3"];
    let result = for_question4(&number_list);

    println!("call index without reference {:p}", number_list[0]); // 0x103d23d5d
    println!("call index with reference {:p}", &number_list[0]); // 0x7fea9c405de0
    println!("call index with two reference {:p}", &&number_list[0]); // 0x7ffeebf46f80
}
```

Comment: Hey!
I think you misunderstand. The `[]` operator is evaluated BEFORE the `&` operator. The `[]` operator auto-dereferences. (That's at least my understanding of how Rust works)

Comment: Oh, it does! They mentioned it in [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/array-expr.html?highlight=index#array-and-slice-indexing-expressions) Thank you so much!

Comment: [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[]` operator is evaluated *before* the `&` operator. The `[]` operator auto-dereferences.

Here are some examples:

```rust
fn main() {
    let n = vec!["1", "2", "3"];

    println!("      n[0]  {:p}", n[0]);
    println!("   (&n)[0]  {:p}", (&n)[0]);
    println!("  (&&n)[0]  {:p}", (&&n)[0]);
    println!("     &n[0]  {:p}", &n[0]);
    println!("    &(n[0]) {:p}", &(n[0]));
    println!(" &((&n)[0]) {:p}", &((&n)[0]));
    println!("&((&&n)[0]) {:p}", &((&&n)[0]));
}
```

```
      n[0]  0x5597b8ccf002
   (&n)[0]  0x5597b8ccf002
  (&&n)[0]  0x5597b8ccf002
     &n[0]  0x5597b9f3fad0
    &(n[0]) 0x5597b9f3fad0
 &((&n)[0]) 0x5597b9f3fad0
&((&&n)[0]) 0x5597b9f3fad0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out thanks to @Finomnis

It was index operator ([]) that did the auto-dereference. According to [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/array-expr.html?highlight=index#array-and-slice-indexing-expressions):

> For other types an index expression a[b] is equivalent to *std::ops::Index::index(&a, b), or *std::ops::IndexMut::index_mut(&mut a, b) in a mutable place expression context. Just as with methods, Rust will also insert dereference operations on **a** repeatedly to find an implementation.